# Lorenz curve and Gini coefficient for measuring classifier performance

Tags: classification, roc, auc, gini, lorenz-curve

I often use a [ROC curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) and the [area under that curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_Under_Curve) as a measure of classifier accuracy in 2-class problems, e.g:

```
#Load a dataset
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

#Build a model
library(caret)
model <- train(Class~., data=Sonar, method='gbm', tuneLength=1, trControl=trainControl(method='cv'))
model

#ROC curve and AUC
library(pROC)
pMal <- predict(model, newdata=Sonar, type='prob')[,2]
roc(Sonar$Class, pMal, plot=TRUE)
>Area under the curve: 0.9705

#Lorez curve and gini?
```

[image]

In a similar manner, I would like to be able to plot the [lorenz curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve) and calculate the [gini coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) for my classifier.  I know `Gini = 2*AUC-1`, but I'm not actually sure how to calculate it on it's own.  Furthermore, every application of a lorenz curve I've seen looks at univariate data (e.g. income distribution).  **How do I calculate a lorenz curve when I have 2 parameters: the predicted probability of the positive class, and the positive class itself?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lorenz curve is also known under the name of "[lift curve](http://mrvar.fdv.uni-lj.si/pub/mz/mz3.1/vuk.pdf)" when applied to classification/ranking. For a given range of predicted probability values, the lift represents a multiplicative increase in the positive class's rate (due to a given predictive model) over a random guess.

[rocr package](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/ROCR.pdf) can calculate lift values/curves (the manual also has a concise definition of the lift). The Gini index can be calculated from the area under the lift curve (I typically use cumulative lift value at a given predicted probability threshold instead since it is easier to relate to business metrics)